# HttpClient pass multiple simple parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to do a `POST` from one `controller` to another `controller`. Both `controller`'s are from different projects. One project is serving to simulate the presentation layer (which I will call the test project here).

From the test project I'm trying to pass 2 simple `string` parameters to the other controller which I will call the process.

```
var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", param.Id.Value));
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("type", param.Type.Value));
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
       client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("nl-NL"));

       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

       string token = param.token.Value;
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

       var response = client.PostAsync("/api/Process/Product", content).Result;

       if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
           var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
           return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
       }

       return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "fail");
}
```

And in the process controller, I'm trying to receive it like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Product(string id, string type)
{
    return null;
}
```

But it never reaches this `controller`. I always get a "not found status code".

So how can I pass 2 simple parameters with `HttpClient()`?

Comment: Why don't you use GetAsync? Meaning changing you Verb from Post to Get.

Comment: Because I can only pass 1 parameter with `GET`. Though I tried your solution, but didn't work. It's not comming in the process `controller`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use Get  instead of Post for simple type parameters.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("nl-NL"));

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    string token = param.token.Value;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    // New code:
    var response = await client.GetAsync( string.format("api/products/id={0}&type={1}",param.Id.Value,param.Id.Type) ).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
    }

    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "fail");
}
```

In the API side you can do like this.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Product(string id, string type)
{
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to do something with route in attribute? Like what they describe in this post: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Yes you use attribute routing or you can update your routing config to fit this.

Comment: Or you can give a try like product/id=value&type=value

Comment: You're last comment did the trick, please update your answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Great answer @NMK. Crazy it doesn't have building parameters for you built-in to it, and they make you format it yourself, but either way this is the key!

Comment: will this work without a '?' ?? I didn't think that was proper formatting

Answer (score 2):

When receiving a post you must specify [FromBody] in the parameters for the method to be called

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Product([FromBody]string id, [FromBody]string type)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This will not work... You cannot have more than one [FromBody] attribute
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I am totally in love with it, but I used anonymous types and dynamics to handle this in the past... (Note the config differences for using PostAsJsonAsync(). I forgot these initially.)

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));    
client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/User/UpdateLastLogin", new { UserId = userId, ApplicationId = applicationId });
```

Receiving controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void UpdateLastLogin([FromBody]dynamic model)
    {
        _userRepository.UpdateLastLogin((int)model.UserId, (int)model.ApplicationId);
    }
```

In WebApiConfig.Register():

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

The other approach, which I passed on, is to create a completely new set of strongly types models for every one of these calls. I didn't want to, as I had a ton of them to make to a WebAPI.

Comment: Tried your solution too, but didn't work either. It's never hitting the breakpoint in the process `controller`.

Comment: Are you debugging both applications?

Comment: Yes. Every other method with a breakpoint inside the process `controller` gets hit. Just this one doesn't. Fiddler is also marking the url in red. But when inspecting it, it doesn't show anything that tells me what the problem might be.

Comment: If you haven't heard of it, this is a very helpful tool in debugging situations like this. http://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: With that, you should be able to post with two parameters (id, type) to verify routing, etc. You won't be able to leave that controller with two parameters, though. You will need to use a single strongly typed object, or a dynamic.

Comment: (Edited answer to include some extra config for posting as JSon.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example you can use for `WinForms`, `WPF` or `Console` apps

**Client code**

```
async Task<CalendarView> GetData(int month, int year, int deviceTypeID)
        {
            var result = new MSOCommon.CalendarView();
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                var calendarRequest = new CalendarRequest()
                {
                    Month = month,
                    Year = year,
                     DeviceTypeID = deviceTypeID,
                    UserInfo = Program.UserInfo
                };

                var url = Properties.Settings.Default.ServerBaseUrl + string.Format("/api/calendar/Calendar");

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, calendarRequest.AsJson());
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)    // Check the response StatusCode
                {
                    var serSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                    {
                        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
                    };    

                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MSOCommon.CalendarView>(responseBody, serSettings);
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.Error(Properties.Resources.DATACannotGetCalendar);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(Properties.Resources.DATACannotGetCalendar + " " + ex.Message);
                logger.Error(ex);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

**Controller server-side code**

```
 [HttpPost()]
        public CalendarView Calendar(CalendarRequest calendarRequest)
        {
            logger.Info(string.Format("Get calendar for month {0} and year {1} ", calendarRequest.Month, calendarRequest.Year));
            // TODO Check username
            var result = new CalendarView();

            using (var db = new MSOnlineEntities())
            {
                result =   db.Calendars.Include("CalendarDetails")
                     .Where(x => x.CMonth == calendarRequest.Month && x.CYear == calendarRequest.Year && x.CDeviceTypeID == calendarRequest.DeviceTypeID).ToList()
                     .ConvertAll(x => new CalendarView
                     {
                         ID = x.ID,
                         CMonth = x.CMonth,
                         CYear = x.CYear,
                         CDays = x.CDays,
                         CDeviceTypeID = x.CDeviceTypeID,
                         ClosedAtTime = x.ClosedAtTime,
                         ClosedByUser = x.ClosedByUser,
                         IsClosed = x.IsClosed,
                         CalendarDetails = x.CalendarDetails.ToList().ConvertAll(d => new CalendarDetailView
                         {
                             ID = d.ID,
                             CalendarID = d.CalendarID,
                             MachineID = d.MachineID,
                             MachineName = d.DATA_MACHINE.Name,
                             D1 = d.D1 ?? -1,
                             D2 = d.D2 ?? -1,
                             D3 = d.D3 ?? -1,
                             D4 = d.D4 ?? -1,
                             D5 = d.D5 ?? -1,
                             D6 = d.D6 ?? -1,
                             D7 = d.D7 ?? -1,
                             D8 = d.D8 ?? -1,
                             D9 = d.D9 ?? -1,
                             D10 = d.D10 ?? -1,
                             D11 = d.D11 ?? -1,
                             D12 = d.D12 ?? -1,
                             D13 = d.D13 ?? -1,
                             D14 = d.D14 ?? -1,
                             D15 = d.D15 ?? -1,
                             D16 = d.D16 ?? -1,
                             D17 = d.D17 ?? -1,
                             D18 = d.D18 ?? -1,
                             D19 = d.D19 ?? -1,
                             D20 = d.D20 ?? -1,
                             D21 = d.D21 ?? -1,
                             D22 = d.D22 ?? -1,
                             D23 = d.D23 ?? -1,
                             D24 = d.D24 ?? -1,
                             D25 = d.D25 ?? -1,
                             D26 = d.D26 ?? -1,
                             D27 = d.D27 ?? -1,
                             D28 = d.D28 ?? -1,
                             D29 = d.D29 ?? -1,
                             D30 = d.D30 ?? -1,
                             D31 = d.D31 ?? -1
                         })
                     }).FirstOrDefault();

                return result;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[HttpGet]` instead of `[HttpPost]` on the server

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = 
 await client.GetAsync(string.format("api/product?id={0}&type={1}",param.Id.Value,param.Id.Type);
```

The difference between my answer and the NMK's accepted answer is the `?` instead of the `/`
This is what worked for me